# Creating HBaseAdmin which connects to HBaseTestingUtility

Tags: java, unit-testing, hadoop, junit, hbase

I'm writing a code which manipulates data stored in HBase. I want to write also a test for this code. I want to use HBaseTestingUtility in my test, hence, in my @BeforeClass I create new instance of HBaseTestingUtility and I start the mini cluster:

```
    @BeforeClass
public static void setUpClass() throws Exception {
    utility = new HBaseTestingUtility();
    utility.startMiniCluster();
}
```

It works good. However, I cannot connect to this embedded cluster in my code which is being tested. In the code I have:

```
Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();

try (HBaseAdmin admin = new HBaseAdmin(config))
{
   //code which manipulates the data
}
```

Unfortunately when new HBaseAdmin is created I'm getting a ConnectionError exception:

> 2013-11-21 11:20:35,778 WARN  [main-SendThread(0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2181)] zookeeper.ClientCnxn (ClientCnxn.java:run(1089)) - Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
>   java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
>       at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
>       at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:692)
>       at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:350)
>       at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1068)

When I try another apporach to create HBaseAdmin:

```
try (HBaseAdmin admin = new HBaseAdmin(HBaseCacheTest.utility.getConfiguration()))
{
   //code which manipulates the data
}
```

it works (note that here I'm accessing the instance of HBaseTestingUtility via HBaseCacheTest.utility). 
Obviously this is not a good approach as I don't want to have a production code which depends on the testing code.

One approach I see to work here is to make it possible in my production class to set the Configuration and use this setter method in my tests. 
However, I believe that there should be another way to connect to the embeded mini cluster created with HBaseTestingUtility.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You should not create a new Configuration object, but use the one provided by HBaseTestingUtility:

```
HBaseAdmin admin = testingUtility.getHBaseAdmin();
```

Also, if you need configuration only you can use this one:

```
testingUtility.getConfiguration()
```

Just rechecked it in my UT. I'm using HBase 0.96-hadoop2

Hope this helps :)